# How to disable road highlighting on defaultLayer on HERE maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to disable the highlighting from roads in HERE maps javascript API.
How I can disable highlighting directly in defaultLayer.normal.map of the H.Map?

I can't find method in documentation and also not by searching on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check different styles available from [Map Tile API](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/map_tile_hlp/2.1.70.2/Map%20Tile%20API%20v2.1.70.2%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)

and use the style you chose as belowin JS code:

```
let platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: APPLICATION_ID,
    app_code: APPLICATION_CODE,
    useCIT: true,
    useHTTPS: false
});

// create default layers
let defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// cree own provider 
let provider = new H.map.provider.ImageTileProvider({
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    getURL: function (col, row, level) {
        let scheme = "normal.day.grey";

        return ['http://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/', '2.1', '/', "maptile", '/', 'newest', '/',
            scheme,
            '/', level, '/', col, '/', row, '/', '256', '/', "png",
            '?lg=', "FRE",
            '&app_code=', APPLICATION_CODE, '&app_id=', APPLICATION_ID]
            .join('');
    }
});
var layer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(provider);

// create H.map
map = new H.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    layer, {
        center: { lat: 48.8, lng: 2.3 },
        zoom: 10
    });
```